# Style element only when it contains clipped text

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I'm looking a way to provide some feedback to the user when the text is clipped by the `overflow: hidden` property (eg. display ellipsis or arrow at the end of text, or have it in different color), so the user knows when he can hover on the element to display more content.

Here's what I came up for now:
https://jsfiddle.net/5u259u9r/6/

Note the behavior of the second image.

I wan't the text to be styled differently only if it is to long to fit in the box limited by `max-height`.

Is this even possible with pure css?
I've been playing with `text-overflow`, but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this to your CSS

```
.gallery li .desc > div {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  display: -webkit-box;
}

.gallery li:hover .desc > div {
  overflow: visible;
  white-space: normal;
  display: block;
}
```

You need to change the value of this `-webkit-line-clamp: 2;` based on the number of lines you want to display before adding the ellipsis.

Working JSFiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/5u259u9r/7/

Updated JSFiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/5u259u9r/8/

Comment: Thanks, this works with one assumption: `max-height` is equal to `line-height`. What if `max-height` is eg. twice`line-height`?

Comment: Even in that case it will work. Just tried doubling the max-height in the JSFiddle. And it worked well.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I mean how to display no more than two lines of text (so the ellipsis would be appended at the end of the second line). `text-overflow` won't work in this case.

Comment: In that case, You could use `-webkit-line-clamp: 2;` property. See my updated answer.

Comment: Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, looks ok in Chromium, but the ellipsis is not displayed in Firefox (Ubuntu, Firefox 44.0.2)